# Why is JavaScript executing DOM statements last when a variable is true?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've been solving a ton of bugs today, but this one bug I can't work out.

The code below is for a very simple logon page. The only correct username at this point is 'admin' and the only correct password, for that user, is 'password'.

Here is the code:

```
function loginauth() {
  var success = false;
  var Xusername = document.getElementById("lsr1u").value;
  var Xpassword = document.getElementById("lsr1p").value;
  if (Xusername == "admin") {
    if (Xpassword == "password") {
      success = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "The username or password is incorrect."
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "The username or password is incorrect."
  }
  if (success) {
    if (success) {
      document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = ("s");
    }
    // successful login operations here
    alert("success");
    //document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = "success"; //remove when done
    alert("x");
  }
}
```

For whatever reason, the last chunk of is code is executing, but with this catch: the two alert boxes that pop up (success) and then (x) pop up **before** the document.getElementById changes the innerHTML for the paragraph with id "wrong" to "s".

There is nothing in this code I can find that would be causing a problem. I even double nested the success if/else statements to make sure that the DOM would get changed first. But that didn't work.

Note that the two other document.getElementByIds on this page for "The username or password is incorrect" work perfectly fine, as they are supposed to (var success if false then). And if I don't have any alert boxes in my success if/else block at the end, then it never even runs that DOM code and it never changes to 's'. So something very strange is going on today.

This only happens in Chrome, I think. It works okay in Internet Explorer and Edge.

Comment: Why would you put an `if (success)` test inside a statement block conditioned by another `if (success)` test?

Comment: @Pointy I did that just as a test. It wasn't originally like that. But doing so didn't fix my problem. It doesn't work whether or not that is there

Comment: Variables don't randomly change values for no reason.

Comment: @Pointy My problem is not with the variables. I know this code is sloppy but everything else is working fine

Comment: There's simply no guarantee that the call to `alert()` will force DOM updates to happen. Browsers tend to defer DOM updates until the last possible moment.

Comment: @Pointy If those alert statements are not there, the DOM update does not occur at all. You can go to the live demo I have at the bottom of this post to see the problem first-hand

Comment: Your demo page doesn't load for me, but is this a submit handler for a form?

Comment: I think browser do the changes to the DOM asynchronously! And since the alert halt everything, then the changes won't proceed untill the pop up is closed!

Comment: I've just test it this: `document.body.innerHTML = "a"; alert("b");` and the changes didn't happen untill the alert is closed!

Comment: @InterLinked I disagree https://jsfiddle.net/usdp7xLk/

Comment: There is no actual problem here.

Comment: This is browser dependent. Chrome has the habit to delay page changes so that an alert will be processed first. Other browsers may do things differently.

Comment: @Pointy That code looks more or less the same. So it works on jsfiddle but not on my server - do you know what the problem could be then?

Comment: @Interlinked: I can confirm that with breakpoints set, the DOM update does happen, and the calls occur in the right order. (and i do see the somewhat odd result you are seeing with no breakpoints set).

Comment: @InterLinked there is no problem. You shouldn't be using `alert()` for debugging anyway; use `console.log()`.

Comment: @InterLinked in FF, your link works as expected in all scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the alerts to pop up after the changes then just wrap them inside a `setTimeout` like this:

```js
document.body.textContent = "hhh";

setTimeout(function() {
  alert("x");
}, 0);
```

Comment: Do I need the document.body thing or can I just the setTimeout part?

Comment: @InterLinked The `document.body` was just a demonstration, you need just the `setTimeout` bit!

Comment: So the stuff in the setTimeout block runs first or after? It looks like I am supposed to put the stuff I want running first IN the block??

Comment: I think that's the changing of the DOM is asynchronous, and since asynchronous things are left fo later, I made the alerts asynchronous as well so the order will be kept.

Comment: It's still not working. I implemented these changes on the live webpage. You can view the code if you View Page Source. I tried it both ways

Comment: You need take the alerts inside the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Variable is innocent here. The problem is about the syncronization between javascript execution and DOM rendering. Although javascript is single threaded, DOM operations are being done by another thread and they wait each other.

So call stack has some code to execute and DOM rendering will wait the stack to be empty. But before that you are showing user an alert window which freezes **everything**. So the DOM's turn never comes until the user clicks the button on alert window.

A deferring method like the one Ibrahim has suggested, shifts the execution time of the block to the **next** JS event loop so the DOM can have **one turn to update itself** before that blocking code.

I suggest watching the related part of [this video](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ?t=560) for more info.

Comment: Exactly! you nailed it! Good explanation!

Comment: Writing to the `.innerHTML` property is the source of the desyncronization between the JavaScript execution and the DOM rendering.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `alert()` pauses javascript execution and page rendering until the the alert box has been closed.

That's why I often overwrite `alert()` with a **custom popup function** that does not freeze javascript and also looks the same in all browsers.

Apart from that, I recommend to simplify the code:

```
if (Xusername === "admin" && Xpassword === "password") {
    document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "s";
    alert("success");
    //document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = "success"; //remove when done
    alert("x");
} else {
    document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "The username or password is incorrect.";
}
```

Note that

```
if (success) {
    if (success) {
       ...
```

is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You may want not populate the `innerHTML` of a `DOMElement` because it is the source of your message synchronization issue.

Explanation:

the `innerHTML` property is a serialized text/HTML representation of the whole child node tree attached to the element.

Giving write access to the `innerHTML` is an archaism mostly as old as `document.write`, that persist not to break the legacy JavaScript web sites.

If backward compatibility was not an issue, this property would be **read-only**.

I mean, avoid it, *really*!

When you write to it, the browser engine has to de-serialize, validate the HTML syntax before it can create a Document node tree or a Document fragment to attach as a child of the node.

This de-serialization task of the replacement `.innerHTML` property, is done only once the execution of your JavaScript has ended; because the browser engine does not know if or when you may alter again this string property in your code, and it can not be sure you provided a valid HTML or if the string is final complete at any moment. So it make a guess that once your JavaScript ends its execution, the string will not change. Then and only then, it can start parsing the string (de-serializing) it into some child node tree.

The new `innerHTML` you provide, is only de-serialized once the whole document tree has been resolved.

A better practice here: is to construct text nodes, since your message is only made of text.

If you need to attach HTML elements, then build these with code, and attach your built DOMNodes tree as child of the selected DOMElement.

Here is your `.innerHTML` code replaced by:

- Creation of a text node with `createTextNode("your text")`
- Attachment of the text node as child of the element with `.appendChild(DOMNode)`

This save the browser engine from tasking a de-serialization and all the trouble it has with interpreting a new piece of text/HTML before it can make it a DOMNode to attach to the element.

```
function loginauth() {
  var success = false;
  var Xusername = document.getElementById("lsr1u").value;
  var Xpassword = document.getElementById("lsr1p").value;
  if (Xusername == "admin" && Xpassword == "password") {
    success = true;
  } else {
    document
      .getElementById("wrong")
      .appendChild(
        document.createTextNode('The username or password is incorrect.')
      )
  }
  if (success) {
    if (success) {
      document.getElementById("wrong").appendChild(document.createTextNode('s'));
    }
    // successful login operations here
    alert("success");
    //document.getElementById("author").appendChild(document.createTextNode('success')); //remove when done
    alert("x");
  }
}
```