# Combining multiple IF ELSE statements into AND statements causes script to stop working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The following code worked properly, but [another user recommended combining statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333413/why-is-javascript-executing-dom-statements-last-when-a-variable-is-true/42345465#42345465) to make my code more efficient and less redundant. I implemented these changes, believing that this wouldn't cause any issues, but instead it brought my entire function to a halt.

```
function loginauth() {
var success = false;
/*roles (privilege levels) are defined as follows:
    priv0   =   User is not logged in
    priv1   =   User is logged in using the account "guest"
    priv2   =   User is logged in using a standard user account
    priv3   =   User is logged in using an elevated user account
    priv4   =   User is logged in using an administrator account
    priv5   =   User is logged in using the super administrator account
*/
var Xusername = document.getElementById("lsr1u").value;
var Xpassword = document.getElementById("lsr1p").value;
if (Xusername == "administrator") {
    if (Xpassword == "5YPwP7$luJailk1b2TCAdSEp7ZCfHUdRfwYm3mwc!1D3BP3ML8^00uoUXIncN8N") {
        success = true;
        role = "priv5";
        userFN = "Administrator";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "The username or password is incorrect."
    }
}
else if (Xusername == "guest") {
    if (Xpassword == "guest") {
        success = true;
        role = "priv1";
        userFN = "Guest";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "The username or password is incorrect."
    }
}
else if (Xusername == "admin") {
    if (Xpassword == "AdminPassw0rd$0") {
        success = true;
        role = "priv4";
        userFN = "Admin";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "The username or password is incorrect."
    }
}
else if (Xusername == "jdoe") {
    if (Xpassword == "E2HfYrhyGEwcdWnAVgVD") {
        success = true;
        role = "priv2";
        userFN = "John Doe";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "The username or password is incorrect."
    }
}
else {
    document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "The username or password is incorrect."
}
if (success) {
    document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = ("");
    setTimeout(function() {
        nextauth();
    }, 475);
}
}
```

Simply combining multiple if statements into a single and statement causes the function to stop working:

```
function loginauth() {
var success = false;
var Xusername = document.getElementById("lsr1u").value;
var Xpassword = document.getElementById("lsr1p").value;
if (Xusername == "administrator" && Xpassword == "5YPwP7$luJailk1b2TCAdSEp7ZCfHUdRfwYm3mwc!1D3BP3ML8^00uoUXIncN8N") {
    success = true;
    role = "priv5";
    userFN = "Administrator";
}
}
else if (Xusername == "guest" && Xpassword == "guest") {
    success = true;
    role = "priv1";
    userFN = "Guest";
}
else if (Xusername == "admin" && Xpassword == "AdminPassw0rd$0") {
    success = true;
    role = "priv4";
    userFN = "Admin";
}
else if (Xusername == "jdoe" && Xpassword == "E2HfYrhyGEwcdWnAVgVD") {
    success = true;
    role = "priv2";
    userFN = "John Doe";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "The username or password is incorrect."
}
if (success) {
    document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = ("");
    setTimeout(function() {
        nextauth();
    }, 475);
}
}
```

Absolutely *NOTHING* else has been changed.

Comment: this code works? like in, you using that code? like in production or so?

Comment: @Thomas The code on the top did work. The code on the bottom did not. Anyways, Daniel has resolved my issue

Comment: That's not my point. My point is that you have hardcoded usernames and passwords in your JavaScript. Anyone can read them in clear text. Can create new ones, including new roles and inject them into your script. That's like having no authentification at all. Everybody can log in as Admin or whatever he/she wants.

Comment: @Thomas I realize that, this is an extremely basic example. And not everyone knows how to do that either. And you can't just "inject whatever you want" into the page. When you fresh, all the changes you made go away, and the REAL page is still unmodified. It's a deceptively easy way to make something easy look more complex than it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two closing braces after the first `if` statement, and this is closing your `loginauth` method at that point.

The rest of the code would not be evaluated as part of that method call.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.